# DAE with (almost) linear constraints

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of the form:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}x^i &= a^i_jx^j \notag\\
\sum_i x^i &= 1 \notag
\end{align}$$

where $x^i = x^i\left(t\right)$, $t\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and the $a^i_j$ are constant. For my purposes, it would be best to cast this as a descriptor system:

$$\begin{align}
E\dot{x} &= \tilde{A}x + Bu
\end{align}$$

where I have stuck the 'one' term in the constraint equation in as a control input, and will thus have to define $u\left(t\right) = 1$.

My question is basically is this a valid way to re-cast the problem (all issues associated with initial conditions aside) or is the inclusion of the constraint in this manner an invalid approach?

As an example, let's say I have:

$$\begin{align}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  \dot{x}^1\\
  \dot{x}^2\end{array}\right) &=
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    a & b\\
    c & d\end{array}\right]
%
    \left(\begin{array}{c}
  x^1\\
  x^2\end{array}\right) \notag \\
%
x^1 + x^2 &= 1 \notag
\end{align}$$

Can I legitimately re-cast this as:

$$\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 0\\
  0 & 1\\
  0 & 0\end{array}\right]
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  \dot{x}^1\\
  \dot{x}^2\end{array}\right) &=
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    a & b\\
    c & d\\
    1 & 1\end{array}\right]
%
    \left(\begin{array}{c}
  x^1\\
  x^2\end{array}\right) +
%
  \left[\begin{array}{c}
    0\\
    0\\
    -1\end{array}\right]
%
  u, \,\,\, u\left(t\right) = 1 \notag
\end{align}$$

or does this change the actual nature of the system?

Thanks!

Comment: Your system is overdetermined, as $\dot x^2=-\dot x^1$, resp. the first two equations form an ODE all by themselves whose solution might contradict the last equation.

Comment: Generally, yes, but for my application (which I'm not going to bother expanding on as it's rather off-topic) both the system matrix $A$ and the $x^i$ have structure that will avoid this contradiction and it's matter of valid initial conditions.

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, the structure of $A$ ends up following the constraint equation, making it totally redundant!  Thanks, I missed that altogether--problem solved! :-)